# docker login fails with 400 bad request, for Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

Tags: docker, artifactory

When I attempt `docker login my-company.jfrog.io`.  
 
I get `login attempt to https://my-company.jfrog/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request.` 
The Docker version is 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

I tried the same command with 
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87, I dont see any such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was intermittent. I don't get that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Review your reverse proxy setup first and look at the systemlogs for "requests"

Answer (score 0):

What is the docker access method?

Port method 
Repository path: $ docker login my-company.jfrog.io
subdomain: docker login docker-virtual.my-company.jfrog.io

Based on that, try to log in and see what is happening in the request.log and artifactory.log file.

Else, enable the http debug loggers on Artifactory to get detailed information.

also, enable docker debug loggers and see what is happening from the client end